# How do I print out the lowest value from the results of my query?

Tags: php, echo, min

**I have**

```
var_dump($row[Price]);
```

**which prints out all prices from  my query ($query = "Select * FROM myTable WHERE...")**

*like this:*

```
string(5) "37.00" string(5) "20.00" string(5) "23.00" string(5) "12.00" string(5) "10.00"
```

Now: I would like to print (echo) out just the **Lowest Value** which is  **"10.00"** in this case.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just `SELECT MIN(price) FROM myTable WHERE ...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  // Print out the contents of each row into a table
}
```

Instead of above codes, use following:

```
$list = mysql_fetch_array($result);

function _getPrice($array) {
  return $array['Price'];
}

$prices = array_map('_getPrice', $list);

echo min($prices);
```

#### Alternative [suggest you]

Or you can get MIN with SQL Query like @Teneff said:

```
SELECT MIN(price) FROM myTable WHERE...
```

Comment: I get  Warning:"Wrong parameter count for min()" because min needs to compare two value or array

Comment: You paste `$row[Price]` like array. `$row[Price]` is array or string? have to be array.

Comment: of my understanding (low) is an array because contains different values and from them i need to print out the lowest! I appreciated your help thank you.

Comment: Oo i understood you! Wait a minute

Comment: @user2635574 Try two alternative now

Comment: 1st)) FATAL ERROR! Cannot redeclare _getprice() on line 284 (previously declared in .....) online 281

Comment: @user2635574 You probably use in while loop. Please paste all codes to question.

Comment: 'while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { // Print out the contents of each row into a table}'

Answer (score 0):

You could add ORDER BY to your query, ORDER BY prices ASC. Then print the first element of the array

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate over all strings, convert them to integers and than iterate again to find lowest value. It would be better to use some sort criterion with SQL query and then take first value.

Comment: I will try to convert to integers hmmm, actually i'm quering the database with if statements then filters and orderby